# Passagem de parâmetros de uma Activity para outra

Tags: java, android, listview, intent

Preciso passar o nome de um produto selecionado numa `ListView` para ser apresentado em um `EditText`.

Atualmente estou na tela que o usuário informa o cliente e em seguida abre a tela de novo pedido, nessa tela tenho um botão para selecionar um produto dessa `ListView`.

**Problema:** Quando entro na Activity da lista e seleciono o produto, ele da *start* em uma nova tela de novo pedido reiniciando as informações do cliente e mostrando apenas o nome do produto no `EditText`.

Como eu evito a nova carregar atualizo apenas o `EditText`?

Comment: Esta um bocado confusa, não percebi bem o que pretendes.

Answer (score 5):

Boa tarde, talvez eu tenha ficado um pouco confuso com sua descrição, mas tentarei responder pelo que entendi, para passar as informações de uma activity para outra basta reutilizar o bundle e ir passando adiante de activity em activity.

exemplo:

```
//código para obter o bundle da activity anterior
Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();

//obter alguma informação do bundle
String nome = bundle.getString("nome");

//adiciona alguma informação no bundle
bundle.putInt("idCliente", idCliente);
bundle.putFloat("valorProduto", valorProduto);

//passa o bundle para a próxima activity
startActivity(suaIntent.putExtras(bundle));
```

e quanto a iniciar uma nova tela experimente utilizar o método startActivityForResult ao invés de apenas startActivity para iniciar a lista. Com isso você retorna um resultado para a activity anterior.
[Aqui](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) tem um tutorial sobre como retornar um resultado de uma activity.

Comment: Então eu tinha testado assim, só que quando eu dou um startActivity ou até pelo For result, ele pega a minha activity de novoPedido que contem os dados do cliente e apaga.

Comment: Olha o meu código que tenho no momento.

' Intent intent = new Intent(ListaProdutosBD.this,
    NovoPedidoActivity.class);
  // Usadao para a passagem de parâmetro no Android melhor do que ficar
  // copiando.
  Bundle parametro = new Bundle();
  parametro.putString("nmProd", produtoSel = ((TextView) view).getText()
    .toString());
  // produtoSel = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
  intent.putExtra("produto", produtoSel.toString());

  //startActivityForResult(intent, SELECIONAR_PRODUTO);
  finish();'

Comment: faça a activity for result na tela de pedido, ela vai chamar a lista de produtos e assim que ela terminar, vai retornar com o resultado como no exemplo que tem nessa pergunta do SOen [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

Answer (score 1):

Quando você chama o método `finish();` o Android remove a *activity* da pilha e não tem como retornar para ela. Se não for isso poste as classes para maior entendimento.